# How to load an Erlang module within a Elixir/mix project?

Tags: erlang, elixir

I have an Elixir project managed by mix. When started with `iex -S mix` all Elixir modules within my lib folder get loaded. An Erlang module in an `.erl` file within the lib folder doesn't.

I'd like to know either a) how do I load an Erlang module explicitly from my Elixir code or b) what do I have to do to have mix autoload the Erlang module, too. (Preferably both ;) )

Comment: Why did you put erlang module into `.ex` file in the first place? Put in into `.erl` file.

Comment: Sorry. It _is_ an `.erl` file. I corrected the question. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Erlang modules that get compiled will get included automatically. If your local erlang module is in the `lib/` folder though the problem may be that its not getting compiled.

The mix task that handles compiling erlang modules ([mix compile.erlang](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Compile.Erlang.html)) assumes the default path where the erlang modules are included is in a `src/` directory.

If you'd prefer to place it somewhere else, you can adjust the configuration via the `:erlc_paths` parameter, in your project config in `mix.exs`. A bare bones example would look like:

```
def project do
  [
    app: :test,
    version: "0.1.0",
    elixir: "~> 1.6",
    erlc_paths: ["lib"],
    start_permanent: Mix.env() == :prod,
    deps: deps()
  ]
end
```

Comment: Also, to automatically run the `compile.erlang` task add this as alias to the project definition:

`aliases: ["compile.erlang", "run"]`